# MVC - Which design pattern to use to transform request payload from the Controller to the Model

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I'm using the MVC approach.

So when I'm receiving an *`EntityFilterRequest`* from the body (payload) for PUT/POST verbs, I need to transform the *`EntityFilterRequest`* to an *`EntityFilterRequestModel`* using

```
EntityFilterRequestModel.of(EntityFilterRequest).
```

The `of` method performs:

So basically instead of having the traditionally MVC approach, I have a layer between the `C` and the `M` to perform the conversion between the `*requests` and the `*requestModels` classes.

1. All the necessary casts (String to Integer, Short)
2. Default values for empty fields from the request
3. Performs some check existents entity ids.
4. Build new fields that will be necessary for the model layer.

Is this already a design pattern?
Is there a better approach?

The main idea is to remove all validations describes above from the Model using the classes `EntityFilterRequestModel` and reduce the unnecessary code on the `M` layer.

If you needs more details please add comments and I will try to be more clear.

Comment: MVC doesn't limit the amount of layers in a controller to one, so you haven't done anything non-MVC yet. It has always been controller's responsibility to make the data suitable for the model layer.

Comment: Ok, I agree with you, But is there a better approach to achieve what I am trying to do? Is there an existing design pattern for this?

Comment: There are plenty of libraries that will do the mapping for you, such as Dozer. There's no design pattern for converting one object to another.

Comment: I don't think dozer is exactly what I need because I do more than a mapping between the `EntityFilterRequest` and `EntityFilterRequestModel`. I perform the 4 points listed on the question. Regarding this "new" layer, can I call it the Transform/Mapping Layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as Kayaman said, i don't really think you are adding an extra layer to the MVC (Ok, you can consider this as a "sub-layer" of one of MVC components).

Your intent is to convert / map the request data into a Data Structure suitable to be passed to the model. Basically, you need to map one structure to another and decouple the sender request from it's receiver.

However, in my opinion, you are adding to much responsibility to one object. The converter is doing way too many things. So what you could do is something like:

- The controller delegates the `EntityFilterRequest` -> `EntityFilterModel` conversion to a specific object (say a mapper):
  `requestMapper.map(EntityFilterRequest);`. This mapper can take care of the casting and default values. It's responsibility is to convert a request into a known DataStructure (`EntityFilterModel`) that is suitable to be passed to the model;
- Once you have the `EntityFilterModel`, you can pass it to a `Validator` or even to a `ValidatorChain` that can store multiple `Validators` and, of course, handle several validations;
- After all validations are in place, if all is valid, the `EntityFilterModel` can then be passed the to model itself for further processing;

This way, you have created a set reusable and decoupled components that are orthogonal to each other. E.g., the validators can be used in some other context.

The process involves more of a set of Design Patterns than rather just one. Indeed, a solution to a problem often involves several design partners working together. Nevertheless, take a look to the following one:
https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/chain_of_responsibility

Hope it helps!

Comment: I already try the approach Chain Design Pattern Validation but it's too time consuming to implement. I have time constraints to implements this new layer. But many thanks for your opinion.